# Inline CKEditor save to MySQL using AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a few caption boxes that I want to be able to edit inline and to save these to my database to update a certain record in my table.

For some reason, nothing happens when I click the save button.. not even in the console.

It's just using jQuery at the moment, will I have to use AJAX for this?

If so any tips would be great to point me in right direction as I'm not familiar that much with AJAX.

Here is my code:

index.php

```
          <div class="caption" id="caption1" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 450px;">    
           <?php
            $query3 = "SELECT * From (select * from ckeditor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2) AS name ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
            $show = mysql_query($query3, $con);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($show))
            {
              echo $row['file'];
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="save"><span>Save</span></button>
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function (e) {

                  $("#save").click(function (e) {
                      var data = CKEDITOR.instances.caption1.getData();
                      var options = {  
                           url: "save.php",
                          type: "post",
                          data: { "editor" : encodeUriComponent(data) },
                         success: function (e) {
                           echo "Succesfully updated!";
                         }
                       };
                  }
               });
            </script>
      </div>
```

save.php

```
     <?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "", ""); 
$db = mysql_select_db("castle", $connection); 
//Fetching Values from URL
$data = nl2br($_POST['caption1']);
//Insert query
$query ="INSERT INTO `ckeditor`(`file`) VALUES ('$data')";
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: if you want send ajax - you need send ajax :)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi Pavel - thank you for taking the time to reply. I'm not familiar with Ajax so I'd struggle to get that working.. do you have any idea why my existing code doesn't work? I've been scratching my head for about a day over this.

Comment: you create options in your js, but you forgot send this via ajax. Please add $.ajax(options);

Comment: Pavel i've implemented the code below but still not getting any action when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the data to the server like this;

```
$.ajax({
   url: "save.php",
   data: {
      "editor" : encodeUriComponent(data)
   },
   error: function() {
      //Error
   },
   success: function(data) {
      //Success
   },
   type: 'POST'
});
```

Currently you are just creating an object called 'options'

Your code should look like this;

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {
  var data = CKEDITOR.instances.caption1.getData();
  $.ajax({
   url: "save.php",
   data: {
       "editor" : encodeUriComponent(data)
   },
   error: function() {
      //Error
   },
   success: function(data) {
      alert('Success');
   },
   type: 'POST'
});
```

}

Just a side note, 'echo' doesn't work in js. You need to use 'alert()' or 'console.log()'

Comment: Hi Ted - this is very muchly appeciated, but I've implemented the code and I'm still not getting any action when I press the button.

Comment: I fixed this now.